# Chaining Sql commands in visual basic for MSAccess

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Using Visual Basic and SQL to insert data into a MS Access database..... I have the following code which only adds the value of @username if it isn't already present in the table.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (CustomerID) SELECT @username FROM(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl) As v WHERE Not EXISTS(Select 1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username)"
```

However, I wish to insert another value which doesn't require the same validation check. This value is stored in @password

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (CustomerID, Password) SELECT @username FROM(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl) As v WHERE Not EXISTS(Select 1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username VALUES (@username, @password)"
```

I have tried the above, but it doesn't work.

In summary i simply want to add @username to the database and @password in the same row, but with only @username going through the check.

EDIT:
I have tried `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (CustomerID, Password) SELECT @username, @password FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl) As v WHERE Not EXISTS(Select 1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username)"` but receive a syntax error.

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Comment: OleDB does not use named parameters.  It converts your @name to a ?, so your parameters have to be in index order they appear in the sql string.  Your query has three parameters, but you are supplying only two of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your SQL command:

```
..1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username VALUES (@username, @password)"
`------------------------------------------------^
```

If this line is working for you.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (CustomerID) 
SELECT @username 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM tbl
) As v 
WHERE Not EXISTS(Select 1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username)"
```

then this line should also work:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (CustomerID, password) 
SELECT 
    @username,
    @password
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM tbl
) As v 
WHERE Not EXISTS(Select 1 FROM tbl as t WHERE t.CustomerID = @username)"
```

Comment: @Bill435 you should probably add rest of your code to your original question. Are you adding all the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the solution that you are looking for, but depending on the need i would consider soemthing like the below. I am thinking this be added to the table by looking up @username and adding the @password value in a separate line of SQL. Sorry if i am misunderstanding something, but if you can go around the logic check, why not just add second line of sql to add the value to the table where @username = tbl.username.

something like:
UPDATE tbl
SET [password] = @password
WHERE [username] = @username